# iterative cumsum where sum determines the next position to be added

Tags: r, data.table, self-reference, cumsum

I have a data.table as follows

```
set.seed(5)
x <- data.table(x=sample(1:20,15))

> x
     x
 1:  5
 2: 14
 3: 17
 4: 20
 5:  2
 6: 11
 7:  8
 8: 15
 9: 12
10: 16
11:  3
12: 18
13: 10
14:  4
15: 13
```

and I would like to start at `1` and cumulate values iteratively such that the value of `cumsum()` determines the next number to be added to the sum.

In the example I want to add the first value of `x`, here 5, then jump to value number 5 and add that, here 2, then jump to value number `5+2=7`, here 8, then value number `5+2+8=15`, here 13.

That is, I want to get a vector

```
> res
[1]  1  5  7 15
```

Has anyone any idea for this problem?

Comment: How do you determine how long the result vector should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`

```
accum <- Reduce(function(i, j) i + x$x[i], x$x, accumulate = TRUE)
c(1, accum[!is.na(accum)])
# [1]  1  5  7 15 28
```

or `purrr::accumulate`

```
library(purrr)

accum <- accumulate(x$x, ~ .x + x$x[.x])
c(1, accum[!is.na(accum)])
# [1]  1  5  7 15 28
```

Comment: the purrr-solution is considerably faster, in my case at least. Thanks! I wonder whether the solution can also be used when the incremental variable and the variable indexed are different. For example, starting from `x=1` the corresponding value of `y` is added and at `x=x1+y1`  the corresponding value of `y` is added again and so on. Can't figure it out from the syntax.

Comment: If I'm understanding this new problem correctly you should be able to just replace `x$x` with the second vector (e.g. `y`) you want to use. So e.g. `x$x[.x]` replaced with `y[.x]`

Comment: Almost correct — I meant a second vector within the data table, so `accumulate(x$y, ~ .x + x$y[.x])` then does the trick. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution:

```
i = 1
v = i
sum = 0
while (i <= nrow(x)) {
   v = c(v, i)
   sum = sum + x$x[i]
   i = sum
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that takes how long you want your vector to be and produces a vector of that length:

```
recursiveadd<-function(x, n) {k<-x$x[1]
 for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
     k[i+1]<-sum(x$x[k[i]],k[i])
   }
 k
}

recursiveadd(x,4)
[1]  5  7 15 28
```