# stepwise or cumulative time series involving POSIX

Tags: r, datatable, posix, purrr, self-reference

I have a dataframe with two variables, `time` and `dif`,

```
library(lubridate)
a <- data.frame(time=seq(from=as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:01:00"),to=as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 01:15:00"),by="min"),dif=make_difftime(mins=c(2,3,5,5,5,2,6,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4)))

> a
                  time    dif
1  2019-01-01 01:01:00 2 mins
2  2019-01-01 01:02:00 3 mins
3  2019-01-01 01:03:00 5 mins
4  2019-01-01 01:04:00 5 mins
5  2019-01-01 01:05:00 5 mins
6  2019-01-01 01:06:00 2 mins
7  2019-01-01 01:07:00 6 mins
8  2019-01-01 01:08:00 6 mins
9  2019-01-01 01:09:00 6 mins
10 2019-01-01 01:10:00 6 mins
11 2019-01-01 01:11:00 6 mins
12 2019-01-01 01:12:00 6 mins
13 2019-01-01 01:13:00 4 mins
14 2019-01-01 01:14:00 4 mins
15 2019-01-01 01:15:00 4 mins
```

and I would like to get a sequence that starts at `01:01:00`, adds the value of `dif` and then continues at `01:01:00 + 2 mins = 01:03:00`, then adds the value of `dif` and continues at `01:03:00 + 5 mins = 01:08:00` and so on. The desired output is thus

```
                  time    dif
1  2019-01-01 01:01:00 2 mins
3  2019-01-01 01:03:00 5 mins
8  2019-01-01 01:08:00 6 mins
14 2019-01-01 01:14:00 4 mins
```

I have asked a similar question before ([iterative cumsum where sum determines the next position to be added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780944/iterative-cumsum-where-sum-determines-the-next-position-to-be-added)) but the non-loop solutions there involve `accumulate()` and `Reduce()` which do not seem to function with POSIXct objects. At least they produce the following error `binary '+' is not defined for "POSIXt" objects`.

Does anyone know how to get this?

Comment: IMHO, this is something you should do using a loop...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with digEmAll that a loop is probably going to be a clearer solution than any clever non-loop solution that I can currently think of.

Here's an approach that tries to minimise repeated linear searching or growing data structures by first calculating a map that connects each row to the one that follows by doing a join.

```
a$row <- 1:nrow(a)
b <- data.frame(time_to = a$time + a$dif)
row_map <- merge(a, b, by.x = "time", by.y = "time_to", all.y = TRUE)$row

a$in_output <- FALSE
current_row <- 1

while(!is.na(current_row)) {
  a[current_row, "in_output"] <- TRUE
  current_row <- row_map[[current_row]]
}

a[a$in_output, c("time", "dif")]

                  time    dif
1  2019-01-01 01:01:00 2 mins
3  2019-01-01 01:03:00 5 mins
8  2019-01-01 01:08:00 6 mins
14 2019-01-01 01:14:00 4 mins
```

If you have a lot of data, maybe it'd be better to pre-allocate and/or grow a separate vector of row indexes instead of modifying a new column in the original data, but I hope this helps.