# create sequence by repeated joins

Tags: r, join, data.table, sequence

Suppose I have the following data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
t <- data.table(time=1001:2000, period=round(runif(1000,1,5)), a=round(rnorm(1000)))
p <- data.table(id=1:10, time=sample(1000:1100,5), a=round(rnorm(10)))


 > t[27:38]
    time period  a
 1: 1027      3 -1
 2: 1028      5 -1
 3: 1029      3  0
 4: 1030      4 -2
 5: 1031      4 -2
 6: 1032      4 -1
 7: 1033      3  0
 8: 1034      4  1
 9: 1035      1  0
10: 1036      4  0
11: 1037      1  0
12: 1038      2 -1

> head(p)
   id time  a
1:  1 1027  1
2:  2 1094  1
3:  3 1044 -1
4:  4 1053  1
5:  5 1015  1
6:  6 1027 -1
```

which is similar to data I have posted before as [concatenate periods to get time sequences, simultaneously for different starting points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54731843/concatenate-periods-to-get-time-sequences-simultaneously-for-different-starting) but now has the additional variable `a` that is carried over from `t`.

In contrast to my earlier question, my goal is to create sequences right into `p` by concatenating n of the periods in `t`. For `n=4`, the result would ideally look like this

```
> head(p)
   id time  a
1:  1 1027  1
2:  1 1030 -1 
3:  1 1034 -2
4:  1 1038  1
5:  1 1040 -1
6:  2 1094  1
```

because for id 1, starting at 1027, the sequence is `1027`, `1027+3=1030`, `1030+4=1034`, `1034+4=1038` and `1038+2=1040`, where the increments are taken from `t`. In addition, `t$a` is "taken along" to fill in for `p$a`.

In my earlier question, Jaap has given a fantastic solution to obtain a two-dimensional output with one line per `id`. I wonder whether this can be achieved directly in `p`. Perhaps this can be done using joins of `t` into `p` repeatedly or perhaps there is a more efficient solution (because efficiency is key here).

Comment: The desired output is already given. However, I have changed the text and (hopefully) made it clearer.

Comment: Shouldn't the last row of desired output be `2 1094  1`?

Comment: absolutely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about what you want to do with `a` to "take it along",
but maybe this recursion does what you want,
although I don't know if it's efficient enough:

```
create_sequences <- function(p, n, acc = p) {
  if (n == 0L) return(setkey(acc, id, time))

  next_p <- t[p, .(id, time = time + period, a = x.a), on = "time"]

  create_sequences(next_p, n - 1L, rbindlist(list(acc, next_p)))
}

ans <- create_sequences(p, 4L)
```